# Proxy is unable to parse the return value of webmethod

Tags: c++, webservice-client

I have C++ application which consumes a .net webservice. I am able to call the webmethod.  The webmethod is returning a string value. But the proxy is unable to parse the return values.

```
HRESULT hr = ws.GetFieryIP(str, &ptr, &ptr1);
```

ws is the proxy generated when i added the web reference.The value of hr is e_fail. There is no other information. When I debug the app I found that the Beginparse() method inside GetFieryIP() method is returning this value.

What may be the error? Is there any tool to monitor the calls?

Comment: You haven't given anywhere near enough information to provide an answer. What are you expecting? What do you get instead? How do you know it's the proxy that's having problems? Have you tried bypassing the proxy?

Comment: I have edited the question.How do I bypass the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out the error from the information supplied, but with Fiddler2 you can trace the requests and hopefully see the problem.

Comment: I am getting SOAPCLIENT_PARSE_ERROR. When I a access the website using a visual studio 2008 client application , I am not getting any error. I am only getting this error when I use a c++ app as a client.